# If current user does not have permission to a particular page, how it should be handled?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to handle the scenario in my application that if a user does not have permissions to view a particular aspx page, then an error message should pop up.
How should I handle that?
Should I redirect user to a specific error aspx page and display error there?
Navigate back to the original page (previous page)?
Whats the best way to deal with this?

Comment: redirect them to a login page. Provide the option to navigate back from there to the sites homepage.

Comment: Are you able to block them from even navigating to the page? If they don't have permission to a page, don't show a link that takes them there.

Comment: Yes I am able to hide the links using which they can navigate to such page. But what if they type in the page manually in address bar somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting is IMO a bad idea, it just confuses the user. Transfer the request on the server (e.g. `Server.Transfer` or similar; in MVC, you might have a separate view for permission errors etc.). This way, the user can easily go back to where he came from (instead of being redirected in a loop when he tries to go back), and if he logs in on the error page, you can just refresh to apply the new permissions.

On HTTP level, you're not supposed to redirect on permission issues. You either return status code `401`, if the user is not logged in and allow him to log in (useful for windows authentication, for example), or `403` if he's logged in but doesn't have permissions, or if you want to use your own login form (and error message). If in doubt, use `403`. If doubly in doubt, even `200` *might* be fine as well; some browsers might ignore your response completely when you issue a `403`.

The same way, the user can still use bookmarks and send links to friends.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to main page or home page of your application and should show error there, because if you navigate to custom error page it will be use less effort and if you navigate back to original page then user will think that application is not working properly

Comment: but once I am back to Homepage, how can I show error message? or HOw do I know I have to show error message?

Comment: you have various way like you can use viewstate or session as flag. If user have not aceess on that page you can set that flag true and use that flag on home page to check that if it is true. if it is ture then you can show your error